# Convert data objects to XML for use with XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I am making a customer profile A how they are header and data about each visit. 
I have gotten my data straight into one of many data objects PersonHeader ph, and StoreVisits sv:

```
oCustDetails = ActiveCustDetails.GetActiveCustDetails(custNumber, Convert.ToString(regionNumber));

    ph.FirstName = oCustDetails.firstName;
    ph.LastName = oCustDetails.lastName;
    ph.MiddleName = oCustDetails.miName;
    ph.Height = oCustDetails.height;
    ph.Weight =oCustDetails.weight;
```

`List<sv>` you get the idea.

Now how can I load these two objects into a

```
XmlDocument personVisits = new XmlDocument();

personVisits.Load(  ??? )
```

Do I have to write these data objects to disk to read into personVists?

I also need to associate an xslt file for presentation.  Can that be done in the same conversion to xmlDoc or do I come back in a second pass for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the CustDetails class into XML using the [XMLSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and create the output file after the transform using the [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (CustDetails));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(stream, oCustDetails);
stream.Position = 0;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputPath);
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(stylesheet);
transform.Transform(reader, writer);
reader.Close();
writer.Close();
```